# Shifting between fragments is showing same position of 1st fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I've been struggling for few days on this issue. My project is having 4 fragments which share the same floating button. I have managed to reference the fragments in order to allow the floating button to access each, however although I'm shifting between each fragment, it showing the position of the first one only. here's my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setNavigationViewListener();

    //set the drawer layout and navigation view
    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            //set item selected persist highlight
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            //close drawer
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            //set action as per the item selected
            return true;
        }
    });

    //create an adapter that knows where each fragment is
    final LocationFragmentAdapter adapter = new LocationFragmentAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.getItem(position);

    //set the function for the floating button to add a new item
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "the current fragment " + adapter.getPageTitle(position));
            if(position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if (position == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecipeEditor.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
        }
    });
}
```

this is my fragmentAdapter

```
public class LocationFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

final int count = 4;
private int [] tabTitle = {R.string.inventory_platform, R.string.product_platform, R.string.customer_platform, R.string.order_platform};
private Context mContext;

public LocationFragmentAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(position == 0) {
        return new InventoryFragment();
    }else if(position == 1) {
        return new RecipeFragment();
    }else if(position == 2) {
        return new CustomerFragment();
    }else {
        return new OrderFragment();
    }

}
```

thats my InventoryFragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(STOCK_LOADER, null, this);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState){
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    //set empty activity
    ListView listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.display_view);
    View emptyView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    //create a new cursor adapter
    mCursorAdapter = new PlatformCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null);
    listView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
    //create onClick listener to inflate the editor view
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //create new intent to opend the editor
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditorActivity.class);
            //create Uri to pass the contents of the item selected to the edit view
            Uri currentItem = ContentUris.withAppendedId(StoreEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);
            intent.setData(currentItem);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(STOCK_LOADER, null, this);

    return rootView;
}
```

and my RecipeFragment

```
    }
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(RECIPE_lOADER, null, this);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState){
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    //set empty activity
    ListView listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.display_view);
    View emptyView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    //create a new cursor adapter
    mCursorAdapter = new RecipeCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null);
    listView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
    //create onClick listener to inflate the editor view
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //create new intent to opened the editor
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditorActivity.class);
            //create Uri to pass the contents of the item selected to the edit view
            Uri currentItem = ContentUris.withAppendedId(RecipeEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);
            intent.setData(currentItem);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}
```

I haven't created the last two fragments yet. Please let me know if you can find the error.

The log message is always showing the Inventory Fragment

Comment: In your first code block, where do you update and declare `position`. It would appear that value is not being updated when you want it to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to update the position every time a page is selected using a pager listener

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
             this.position = position
        }

    });
```